# Using userform data, how can I transfer only the first five digits of a field to my database field (crossposted)

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am attempting to move code to a database from my userform and all of my data is transferring perfect including this field, however, I need to add the limitation of only moving the first 5 characters of this field. I believe using 'Left(Cell.value, 5)' in my code should work, but I can't seem to figure out where to insert it.  I do not need to worry about anything being inserted inappropriately as the field is a drop-down combo box with the options they can use.  My line code is below and it works to move the entire field to my database but as I said, I need to limit transfer to only the first five digits.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sheets("Travel Expense Codes").Range("DataStartCodes").Offset(CodesTargetRow, 11).value = cmbOtherExpenseCode
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thinking is correct. You can use `LEFT()` function with combobox like this `Left(cmbOtherExpenseCode,5)`. Check below code.

```
Sheets("Travel Expense Codes").Range("DataStartCodes").Offset(CodesTargetRow, 11).value = Left(cmbOtherExpenseCode,5)
```

Comment: You rock!!!  I can't believe it was that easy and I've spent half of my day today trying to figure it out!!!  Thank you so much!!!  :)